# 301 redirect query string to SEO friendly URLs through .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, seo

I’ve written some code on my .htaccess file which allows the use of SEO friendly URLs instead of ugly query strings. The following code rewrites the SEO friendly version in the browser to the query string version on the server.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^seo/([^/]*)/$ /directory/script.php?size=large&colour=green&pattern=$1 [L]
```

So that the ugly

`http://www.mysite.com/directory/script.php?size=large&colour=green&pattern=striped`

Is now beautiful

`http://www.mysite.com/directory/seo/striped/`

Just to explain the code a bit; `seo` is there to add more keywords to the URL, `/directory/` is the directory in which the .htaccess file is located, parameters `size=large` and `colour=green` never change, while `pattern=$1` can be many different values.

The above code works perfectly. However, the problem is I am now stuck with two URLs that point to exactly the same content. To solve this, I would like to 301 redirect the old, ugly querystrings to the SEO friendly URLs. What I have tried so far does not work - and Google is not being particularly friendly today.

Can anybody offer working code to put in my .htaccess file that redirects ugly to new URL, while retaining the rewrite? Thanks!

Comment: Added further example URLs for clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick:

RewriteEngine On

```
## Redirect to pretty urls
# The '%1' in the rewrite comes from the group in the previous RewriteCond
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !seo
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^size=large&colour=green&pattern=([a-zA-Z]*)$
RewriteRule (.*) /directory\/seo\/%1\/? [L,R=301]

## Rewrite to long url, additional parameter at the end will cause
## the internal redirect not to match the previous rule (would cause redirect loop)
RewriteRule ^directory\/seo\/([^/]*)/$ /directory/script.php? size=large&colour=green&pattern=$1&rewrite [L]
```

You can also match the size and colour if needed, by changing those to regex groups as well, and using the corresponding `%N`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your code; initially there was an internal server error caused by some extra spacing on the last line of your code, which I removed. Now the code results in a redirect loop. Is your code intended to run alongside mine or is it meant to replace it entirely? If I remove my code the re-direct is successful, but it results in a 404 error (seems as if the URL is no longer being re-written) Would be very grateful for your comments.

Comment: Hm, removed the extra space, must've happend when I pasted my answer in.  Anyways...it was meant to replace yours.   I do see a discrepancy now though.  Your initial rule is set to match URLs starting with `/seo` but then your example redirected URL is `/directory/seo`.  My rewrite is set to match the latter.  If you could clear that up, we should be able to get this working.

Comment: thanks for your reply, have managed to get this working using a combination of our code as follows: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !seo`
`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^size=large&colour=green&pattern=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)$`
`RewriteRule (.*) /directory\/seo\/%1\/? [L,R=301]` `RewriteRule ^seo/([^/]*)/$ /directory/size=large&colour=green&pattern=$1&rewrite [L]`

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but this may work...

RewriteRule ^directory/script.php?size=large&colour=green&pattern=(.*)$ /seo/$1/? [R=301,NE,NC,L]

Comment: thanks for your answer; I'm afraid I couldn't get this to work. There is no redirect.